# Truth table list

Tags: python, list, truthtable

My goal is to make a truth table in python and here's my code:

```
from re import findall

string = "xyz"

def getChars(str):
    listChars = findall(r"\w", str)

    return listChars


def createCharsTruthTable(lst):
    n = 2 ** len(lst)

    boolList = [[True for x in range(n)] for j in range(len(lst))]

    num_of_T = n / 2

    for i in range(len(boolList)):
        for j in range(len(boolList[i])):
            if j >= num_of_T:
               boolList[i][j] = False

        num_of_T /= 2

    return boolList

createCharsTruthTable(getChars(string))
```

the problem is that the output is...

```
[[True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False], [True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]
```

The first list got it right. My only problem is the succeeding lists, where in the second list is...

```
[True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

and my question is how do i turn this into...

```
[True, True, False, False, True, True, False, False]
```

Comment: what is your intended formula for **truth**?

Comment: I didnt use any formula as a basis. I simply coded what i think will be the answer to get my expected output.

Comment: Maybe what I 'expect' is different from what you 'expect'? Don't you think it's useful to share in simpler terms what you 'expect' the code to do? Otherwise, how can we as readers of your question judge what the error is in your code if we don't know what it's supposed to do in the first place?

Comment: well my bad dude this is my first time posting a question

Comment: @Absorption, could you point out what you mean by truth table? I think what you mean by truth table is just the value assignments in variable columns of a truth table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table

Comment: What i intended to do is to make a basic truth table without the operators and just the letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just want to create a "truth table" with 1/2 `True` values in the first line, 2x 1/4 `True` in the second line, and so on, such that the columns in that table would be the input for a truth function with that number of parameters.
You can not just use any `j` as the cutoff from when to put `False` into the table, as the pattern is periodic. Instead, you could try dividing the current `j` by a power of 2 and testing whether it's even or odd:

```
cols = 3
rows = 2**cols
boolList = [[True for x in range(rows)] for j in range(cols)]

for i in range(cols):
    for j in range(rows):
        if (j // (2**(cols-1-i))) % 2 == 1:
           boolList[i][j] = False
```

Result for `boolList`:

```
[[True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False],
 [True, True, False, False, True, True, False, False],
 [True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False]]
```

A better way might be to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) instead:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product([True, False], repeat=3))                        
[(True, True, True),
 (True, True, False),
 (True, False, True),
 (True, False, False),
 (False, True, True),
 (False, True, False),
 (False, False, True),
 (False, False, False)]
```

(Note that rows and columns are inversed here, but it might even make more sense this way.)